# How can wait for an array of promises to finish executing, to then store the values returned from each promise in a state array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
const promises = this.state.selectedFile.map(picture => {
          const ref = Firebase.getStorageRef(`/${picture.name}`);
          return ref
            .put(picture)
            .then(() => ref.getDownloadURL());
        });
```

The above code causes a list of files to be uploaded to firebase Storage and then return its URL.

```
Promise.all([promises]).then(
          console.log(promises),
          this.setState({ mage: this.state.mage.concat([promises]) },()=>console.log(this.state.mage)))
```

I then attempted to pass this  `const promises` which is an array of promises,as a parameter to `Promise.all()` which I assumed will wait for all the promises to be fullfilled.

What approach do you suggest?

Comment: `Promise.all([promises])` -> `Promise.all(promises)`

Comment: Always use `Promise.all` for such scenarios or `Promise.allSettled(promises)`, this function returns an array of result with all promises status whether they were resolved or rejected

Comment: I tried the (promises),but it says its not iterable. @tkausl

Comment: @PiyushRana Tried 'Promise.allSettled()'  ,it gets executed before the promise array and does not wait.

Comment: Did you tried that this way:

    **const promises = [promises];
    const responses = await Promise.allSettled(promises);**

or

    **Promise.allSettled(promises).then(results => {});**